# How to locate the webservice Host point

Tags: c#, rest, http, web-services

This is my first question on the Stackoverflow. I decided to ask this question after spending considerable time on the mentioned matter. I recently joined to a company which develops windows applications. It has a server EXE and a client EXE. The Server EXE communicates with a web service to get the latest updates and user registration information. It uses the following code to test the availability of web services.

```
private void testWebService()
{
    if (WebServiceClient.IsValidHttpAddress(txtWebserviceURL.Text))
    {
        WebServiceClient svc = new WebServiceClient(new Uri(txtWebserviceURL.Text), txtWebserviceUserName.Text, txtWebservicePassword.Text);

        string response;
        if (svc.CheckWebResponse(new UserEndPoint(), out response))
        {
            //Mark the webservice url as read only again
            txtWebserviceURL.ReadOnly = true;
        }
        MessageBox.Show(response, "Web Service Reponse", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
    else
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("URL of '{0}' is invalid.{1}{1}It should start with 'http'.", txtWebserviceURL.Text, System.Environment.NewLine), "Web Service URL", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
```

When I let the above method to be executed, eventually it calls the following method and returns an exception - "The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error."

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a web response from the web service on the required endpoint.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="pEndPoint">The endpoint to connect to the web service with.</param>
    /// <returns>The response returned from the web request.</returns>
    private HttpWebResponse GetWebResponse(WebServiceEndPointBase pEndPoint)
    {
        WebRequest fRequest = WebRequest.Create(pEndPoint == null ? this.Url : pEndPoint.GetEndPointUrl(this.Url));
        fRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        fRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + this.Credentials);
        fRequest.Method = "GET";
        fRequest.Timeout = this.Timeout;

        HttpWebResponse fResponse = fRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
        return fResponse != null && fResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK ? fResponse : null;
    }
```

I believe web service is stopped for some reason. As I am new to the company and no information related to the web service is documented, I cannot figure out where the web service is hosted. The web service name is "http://services.mycomanyname.com.au".

**What I did so far.**

- I checked all the servers (windows) that belong to our company and
  checked each IIS server, I couldn't find any hosted service.
- I used the 'dig' command to find more information. I was able to find
  the related IP address to the service, but when I was trying to
  retrieve the Hostname from the IP address, it did not return any
  name.

**What I want**

1. Please advise me to find the location where the web service is hosted. Asking from existing staff is not an option for me at the moment.
2. Please guide me to obtain the cause of the 500 error.

Comment: So you have a hostname, and it resolves to an (internal) IP address, and the service is running, because it returns a 500. What is your question? How to RDP to that server? Or obtaining the cause of the 500 error?

Comment: @CodeCaster I modified the question to make more sense about what I want. Thank you.

Comment: You have the IP. You can RDP to an IP. What more do you need? To obtain the response body for a HttpWebResponse is documented on this site.

Comment: You are correct, but when I try to RDP to the IP address it shows the general error message of "remote desktop can't connect to the remote computer for one of these reasons...."